# Appium for iOS safari apps Environment set up

Tags: appium

Could anyone please help me with the complete steps for testing Safari apps in iOS with the help of Appium

1. How to start the appium server in MAC
2. How should I launch the Simuator an safari for testing?
3. How can I set up Eclipse IDE for development

Answer (score 0):

I have written about iOS-automation using Appium through Java in my recent post on my site [here](http://smritituteja.in/?p=111) .

You can go through the documentation and sample example and let me know in case of any doubts.